# What brightness level of mobile/desktop/laptop we should keep for better eye care?

Tags: vision, eye-strain, light-sensitivity

What is the level on which it doesn't cause or cause less harm to the eyes or doesn't lead to eye dryness or eye vision problems?

My uncle was suggesting me to keep the brightness to a certain high level so that it will not give any effects on sight but I think it will create an itchiness in the eyes.

Answer (score 3):

You can't give accurate values to the exact level of brightness needed for optimal reading. There are several factors that affect such things such as type of display, ambient light, type of work, program you are working with.

If the brightness is reduced to a minimum, it forces the eyes to exert more strain which would damage the eye as excessive eye strain could cause permanent eye damage.

The best thing to do is to apply the [20-20-20](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/321536.php) rule which says that every 20 minutes, look at something 20 feet away for 20 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the brightness of other light in the room. To reduce eye strain you should try to keep your screen at a similar light intensity compared to the rest of the light in the room.

A particular [study showed that eye strain was increased](https://www.drweil.com/health-wellness/body-mind-spirit/vision/can-watching-tv-in-the-dark-hurt-your-eyes/) when watching a bright screen in a dark room.

> "The result of all this testing and observation was that there was less eyestrain, discomfort and visual fatigue when the volunteers watched the movie against a lighted wall. "

For my self, I try to use more ambient lights that point at the ceiling, or by pointing a desk lamp at the wall behind my monitor, so it smooths out the light and doesn't make one spot so bright. You can also find LED lights that stick on the back of a computer, which point at the wall, to increase the amount of ambient light in a room. Try to keep the screen not too much brighter than the other things in the room.